# Scala type alias for list of numeric

Tags: scala, generics, types, polymorphism, alias

Instead of aliasing each and every possible numeric subtype like this,

```
type ICoord = List[Int]
type LCoord = List[Long]
type FCoord = List[Float]
...
```

how to define an alias for any numeric type, having tried

```
import math.Numeric
type Coord[ T <: Numeric] = List[T]  //error: trait Numeric takes type parameters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible. You'd need a context bound `[T: Numeric]` instead of a subtype bound `<:`, but context bounds aren't allowed in type synonyms, only in class or method declarations (which makes sense since they are translated to an additional constructor/method parameter). You'll have to make the implicit available in some other way (which one depends on what you want to do).